# livescript/prelude: repeat is not defined

Tags: livescript, prelude.ls

With prelude.ls in livescript, when I run `repeat 4 'a'`, it gives me `repeat is not defined`, all other function works fine. Encountering the same problem on livescript.net, I guess I missed something simple, what is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use `Str.repeat` at the moment. This might change for a future version.

Comment: For future reference it's: 

`{Str} = require "prelude-ls"`

and `Str.repeat 3 "a" |> console.log`